# Graph Theory Proof Degree Question

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph of order n. Prove that if deg u + deg v ≥ n - 2 for every pair u, v of nonadjacent vertices of G, then G has at most two components.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $G$ has more than two components, pick vertices $u$ and $v$ in different components. Say that these components have $n_u$ and $n_v$ vertices, respectively.

- What is the maximum possible value of $\deg u+\deg v$ in terms of $n_u$ and $n_v$?
- How does $n_u+n_v$ compare with $n$?